# ON / OFF setting for Push notification at app level

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I would like to apply the native feature of ON/OFF toggle for push notifications at app level. When i applied the same in my app and when I switch OFF, i am unable to receive notifications.  However, when I switch ON, i am not receiving notifications.  To have my notifications enabled, I need to uninstall and then install my app.

any possible solution is appreciated.

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345823/ios-how-to-disable-push-notification-at-logout

Comment: You can open native setting app from your app to enable or disable notifications.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app/24952919#24952919

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `UISwitch` control for on/off OR you can also use separate `UIButton` for on/off.

You just need to unregister for remoteNotification by : ( Off )

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];`

When you want to register again then  ( On )

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

For checking ON or OFF iPhone Push Notifications try this code,

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
 // Yes it is..
```