# iOS push notification: Best way to unregister push notification for user when they log out offline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Currently, I have a `GET` method that unregisters push notification when the user logs out offline. I send the user's device token and API Key to the backend and that will unregister the user and disable push notifications. This works well, but there is one issue. If the user logs out offline, this won't work.

The only solution I came up with is to save the API key and device token and wait until the user comes back online. Then, I will send the API request. Not sure how good this solution is, but the only one I came up with that can work.

Edit: My biggest concern is unregistering push notifications when logging out offline which I haven't seen talked about on StackOverflow. Yes, I can unregister push notifications when user logs out, but not when they do it offline.

Edit 2: By unregisterting, I meant letting my server know not to send push notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS - How to disable push notification at logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345823/ios-how-to-disable-push-notification-at-logout)

Comment: Doesn't explain how to unregister push notifications when you log out offline.

Comment: did you see both answers?! a) The accepted answer suggests that you don't unregister, rather just let your server know that it shouldn't be sending notifications. b) The other answer explains how to do the unregistering. c) That being said if you have 2 accounts using the same device...then I'm not sure how you can unregister the notifications at the *device* level...you can only just inform your *server* to not send notifications. If that doesn't help with your question then please elaborate why...

Comment: I've edited my questions. When I say unregistering, I meant letting my server know not to send push notifications. I can't let my server know not to send push notifications if the user logs out offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other way than what you described in your question. What I would also do is call `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()`. This will stop push notifications to a logged out user's phone, but will **not** alert your server of the unregister. Apple states in their docs that you can re-register to notifications after calling this method [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications?language=objc).

When another user logs in you re-register for push notifications and link the device token to their account.