# Disable push notifications programmatically

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking for a way to disable push notifications when the user logs out of the app.

As the user can do this without an internet connection it is not an option to notify the server that this device should no longer receive notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345823/ios-how-to-disable-push-notification-at-logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to @wsnjy.

The following code disables notifications:

```
UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
```